# When set new frame of tableview in viewDidLayoutSubviews app crashes in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, viewdidlayoutsubviews

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (employeeListModel.count > 0) {
        if ([employeeListModel count]*90 < self.view.bounds.size.height-64) {
            CGRect frame = self.empListTableView.frame;
            frame.size.height = [employeeListModel count]*90;
            self.empListTableView.frame = frame;
            //self.empListTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, [employeeListModel count]*90);
        } else {
            self.empListTableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        }
    }
    [self.empListTableView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This method works perfectly in iOS 8 but crashes in iOS 7 , this crashes come from nowhere.

Comment: what do you have on the console? where exactly it crashes?

Comment: I get --  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. EmployeeListVC's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'

Comment: I advise you to change [self.empListTableView layoutIfNeeded] to be [self.view layoutIfNeeded].

Comment: I changed that too but in that case tableview height is still not changing. It remains same as screen height.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while manually adding constraints in code. In code, I was doing the following:
From what I can tell, the issue is that when you disable translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
Solution:
My solution was to move everything to the contentView.

```
    {
   [self.contentView addSubview:someView];
   [self.contentView addSubview:someOtherView];
   [self.contentView addConstraint:...];
}
```